# Why am I getting an invalid cast exception ('Specified cast is not valid.')?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I'm trying to remove an item from a list when a checkbox is checked. I'm using input.kit for the checkbox. I've been able to remove them using an imagebutton but not this checkbox. Here's the xaml:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TodoListItems}" x:Name="todoList">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <FlexLayout JustifyContent="SpaceBetween" Padding="20,0">
                            <ContentView>
                                <FlexLayout AlignItems="Center" >
                                    <input:CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Complete}" 
                                                    CheckChangedCommand="{Binding Path=BindingContext.CompleteTodoCommand, Source={x:Reference todoList}}"
                                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                                    />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding TodoText}" Padding="10,0,0,0" FontSize="Large"/>
                                </FlexLayout>
                            </ContentView>
                            
                            <ImageButton Source="trash_icon.png" 
                                         Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.RemoveTodoCommand, Source={x:Reference todoList}}"
                                         CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                         Scale="1.2" BackgroundColor="White"
                                         />
                            
                        </FlexLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            
        </ListView>
```

And here's the ViewModel:

```
    {
        private ObservableCollection<TodoItem> todoListItems;

        
        public ObservableCollection<TodoItem> TodoListItems
        {
            get { return todoListItems; }
            set { todoListItems = value; }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<TodoItem> completedTodoItems;

        public ObservableCollection<TodoItem> CompletedTodoItems
        {
            get { return completedTodoItems; }
            set { completedTodoItems = value; }
        }



        public TodoListViewModel()
        {
            todoListItems = new ObservableCollection<TodoItem>();
            TodoListItems.Add(new TodoItem("Walk the duggo",false));
            TodoListItems.Add(new TodoItem("Do the washing",false));
            TodoListItems.Add(new TodoItem("Brush off Cheeto dust",false));

            CompletedTodoItems = new ObservableCollection<TodoItem>();
        }
        public ICommand AddTodoCommand => new Command(AddTodoItem);
        public string NewTodoInputValue { get; set; }
        void AddTodoItem() 
        {
            TodoListItems.Add(new TodoItem(NewTodoInputValue));
        }

        public ICommand RemoveTodoCommand => new Command(RemoveTodoItem);
        
        void RemoveTodoItem(object o)
        {
            TodoItem todoItemBeingRemoved = o as TodoItem;
            TodoListItems.Remove(todoItemBeingRemoved);
        }

        public ICommand CompleteTodoCommand => new Command(CompleteTodo);

        void CompleteTodo(object o) 
        {
            
            TodoItem todoItemCompleted = o as TodoItem;
            todoListItems.Remove(todoItemCompleted);

            CompletedTodoItems.Add(todoItemCompleted);
        }

    }
```

Full view model.
I've checked that the observable collection has been initialised and such. Also, the AddToDo and RemoveTodo command works.

```
0x1C in TodoAppXamarin.ViewModels.TodoListViewModel.CompleteTodo at C:\Users\johns\source\repos\TodoAppXamarin\TodoAppXamarin\TodoAppXamarin\ViewModels\TodoListViewModel.cs:64,4
at C:\Users\johns\source\repos\TodoAppXamarin\TodoAppXamarin\TodoAppXamarin\ViewModels\TodoListViewModel.cs(64)
```

that the stack trace?

Edit: I've tried a bunch of things to try and narrow down the problem and it seems that the CompletedTodoItems observable collection doesn't like having items of TodoItem added to it, no matter where this is done. I tried to just add things to it in the TodoListViewModel constructor and I now get the same exception there (well, in the OnCreate function of MainActivity.cs file in the Android folder).

public ObservableCollection CompletedTodoItems { get; set; }

```
    public TodoListViewModel()
    {
        todoListItems = new ObservableCollection<TodoItem>();
        TodoListItems.Add(new TodoItem("Walk the duggo", false));
        TodoListItems.Add(new TodoItem("Do the washing", false));
        TodoListItems.Add(new TodoItem("Brush off Cheeto dust", false));

        CompletedTodoItems = new ObservableCollection<TodoItem>();
        CompletedTodoItems.Add(new TodoItem("Do the dishes",true));
    }

>   0x1F in TodoAppXamarin.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate at C:\Users\johns\source\repos\TodoAppXamarin\TodoAppXamarin\TodoAppXamarin.Android\MainActivity.cs:17,13    C#
```

And mainpage.xaml.cs if that helps.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    TodoListViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ViewModel = new TodoListViewModel();
    }


}
```

Edit2: It seems to be working now after playing around with a few things and putting everything back the same way. The only substantial change is as follows.

```
void CompleteTodoItem(object o)
    {
        TodoItem completedTodoItem=(TodoItem)o;
        
        Console.WriteLine(completedTodoItem.TodoText);
        TodoListItems.Remove(completedTodoItem);
        
        CompletedTodoItems.Add(completedTodoItem as TodoItem);
        Console.WriteLine(CompletedTodoItems.Contains(completedTodoItem));
    }
```

Comment: Could you please include the entire ViewModel ? An InvalidCasException indicates that types are not compatible with each other, but with what you have provied we can't know what the `CompletedTodoItems` is.

Comment: what is the type of `CompletedTodoItems`?

Comment: There it is now. Type of CompletedTodoItems is ObservableCollection<TodoItem>

Comment: Without telling us the stack trace the exception provides, you leave us a riddle to speculate about which line in your code might throw this exception. Not my kind of gig, i have to admit...

Comment: we don't know what "Line 64" is

Comment: Line 64 is CompletedTodoItems.Add(todoItemCompleted);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, I created a demo, but I couldn't reproduce this problem.

Since I cannot see the code of `TodoItem`  ,so I created a class `TodoItem.cs` as follows:

```
public class TodoItem 
    {
        public string TodoText { get; set; }

        public bool Complete { get; set; }
        public TodoItem(string text,bool ischecked) { 
          this.TodoText = text;    
          this.Complete = ischecked;
        }
    }
```

Besides, because class `TodoItem` does not have a single parameter constructor, so I  replaced your code :

```
    void AddTodoItem() 
    {
        TodoListItems.Add(new TodoItem(NewTodoInputValue));
    }
```

With

```
void AddTodoItem()
    {   // add a value for the second parameter 
        TodoListItems.Add(new TodoItem(NewTodoInputValue,false));
    }
```

And the whole code of `TodoListViewModel.cs`  is:

```
   public class TodoListViewModel 
{
    private ObservableCollection<TodoItem> todoListItems;


    public ObservableCollection<TodoItem> TodoListItems
    {
        get { return todoListItems; }
        set { todoListItems = value; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<TodoItem> completedTodoItems;

    public ObservableCollection<TodoItem> CompletedTodoItems
    {
        get { return completedTodoItems; }
        set { completedTodoItems = value; }
    }



    public TodoListViewModel()
    {
        todoListItems = new ObservableCollection<TodoItem>();
        TodoListItems.Add(new TodoItem("Walk the duggo", false));
        TodoListItems.Add(new TodoItem("Do the washing", false));
        TodoListItems.Add(new TodoItem("Brush off Cheeto dust", false));

        CompletedTodoItems = new ObservableCollection<TodoItem>();
    }
    public ICommand AddTodoCommand => new Command(AddTodoItem);
    public string NewTodoInputValue { get; set; }
    void AddTodoItem()
    { // add a value for the second parameter 
        TodoListItems.Add(new TodoItem(NewTodoInputValue,false));
    }

    public ICommand RemoveTodoCommand => new Command(RemoveTodoItem);

    void RemoveTodoItem(object o)
    {
        TodoItem todoItemBeingRemoved = o as TodoItem;
        TodoListItems.Remove(todoItemBeingRemoved);
    }

    public ICommand CompleteTodoCommand => new Command(CompleteTodo);

    void CompleteTodo(object o)
    {

        TodoItem todoItemCompleted = o as TodoItem;
        todoListItems.Remove(todoItemCompleted);

        CompletedTodoItems.Add(todoItemCompleted);
    }
}
```

Comment: The constructor for TodoItem I was using does have a default parameter for the IsChecked property. Maybe that's what's doing it. Will check it in a while.

Comment: Yes, you can try the code I posted above , it works on my side.

Answer (score 0):

`CompletedTodoItems.Add` does not accept type `TodoItem`. An implicit conversion to the correct type is attempted but `TodoItem` is incompatible.